# Issues with creation of authentication using Next Auth, LDAP Active Directory and React hook form

Tags: next.js, jwt, active-directory, ldap, next-auth

I'm new in the concept of Active Directory and LDAP, the only problem is that I'm trying to make a system working with my Active Directory with Next js Authenthication. Unfortunately there are not too many solution or explanations to this argument so I'm stuck or can I make this system work if I can have sort of explanations of what the code is doing.

In my project I have 2 routes, one is the homepage which already contains the login form using React Hook Form (with ShadCn)

```
"use client"

import * as React from "react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label"
import Link from "next/link"

import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { InventoryLoginSchema } from "./schema"
import { z } from "zod"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { toast } from "sonner"


interface UserAuthFormProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> { }

export function UserAuthForm({ className, ...props }: UserAuthFormProps) {

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof InventoryLoginSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(InventoryLoginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
  })

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof InventoryLoginSchema>) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log(responseData);
      // Handle response as needed
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={cn("grid gap-6", className)} {...props}>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="grid gap-2">
            <div className="grid gap-1">
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="username"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="w-full space-y-1">
                    <FormLabel
                      htmlFor="username"
                      className="sr-only"
                    >
                      Username
                    </FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        id="username"
                        placeholder="jdoe"
                        type="text"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoComplete="username"
                        autoCorrect="off"
                        disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                        {...field}
                        className={cn("h-8", form.formState.errors.username && "border-red-500")}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="grid gap-1">
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="password"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="w-full space-y-1">
                    <FormLabel
                      htmlFor="password"
                      className="sr-only"
                    >
                      Password
                    </FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        id="password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoComplete="password"
                        autoCorrect="off"
                        disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
                        {...field}
                        className={cn("h-8", form.formState.errors.password && "border-red-500")}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting || !form.formState.isDirty}
            className="w-full mt-4"
            size='sm'
          >
            Accedi
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

as following I made the enpoint in my pages route API

> /pages/api/auth/signin

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const { username, password } = req.body;

            const session = await getSession({ req });
            console.log(session)

            const missingFields = [];

            if (!username) missingFields.push('Username')
            if (!password) missingFields.push('Password')

            if (missingFields.length > 0) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Dati obbligatori richiesti.',
                    data: {
                        missingFields
                    },
                });
            }

            // Authentication successful, send response with user attributes
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authentication successful', user: username});
        } catch (error) {
            const errorMessage = typeof error === 'string' ? error : error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error';
            res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed', error: errorMessage });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(405).json({ success: false, message: 'Method Not Allowed' });
    }
}
```

and finally in the same folder as the signin endpoint I setup the dynamic nextauth file

> [...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
const ldap = require('ldapjs');
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "LDAP",
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            authorize: (credentials, req): any => {
                try {
                    const client = ldap.createClient({
                        url: process.env.LDAP_URL,
                    });

                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        client.bind(`${credentials?.username}@******`, credentials?.password, (err: any) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log("Successfully Logged In");
                                resolve({
                                    username: credentials?.username,
                                    password: credentials?.password,
                                });
                            }
                            const filter = `(sAMAccountName=${credentials?.username})`;
                            console.log('filter ', filter)
                            // Authentication succeeded, perform LDAP search to retrieve user attributes
                            client.search(
                                'DC=******,DC=******',
                                { 
                                    scope: 'sub', 
                                    filter: filter,
                                    attributes: [
                                        "partOf",
                                    ]
                                },
                                (searchErr: any, searchRes: any) => {
                                    if (searchErr) {
                                        reject(searchErr); // LDAP search failed
                                        return; // Exit the function early
                                    }

                                    const user: any[] = [];

                                    searchRes.on('error', (error: any) => {
                                        reject(error); // Error during LDAP search
                                    });

                                    searchRes.on('searchEntry', (entry: any) => {
                                        console.log("User found");
                                        user.push(entry.attributes);
                                    });

                                    searchRes.on('end', () => {
                                        client.unbind(); // Always unbind after operation
                                        resolve(user);
                                    });
                                });
                        }
                        );
                    });

                } catch (error) {
                    // Authentication failed
                    console.error("Authorization failed:", error);
                    return null; // Authorization failed
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/'
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            // Add custom fields to the JWT token
            if (user) {
                token.user = user; // Include user object in the token
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            // Add custom fields to the session
            if (token?.user) {
                session.user = token.user; // Include user object in the session
            }
            return session;
        },
    }
})
```

As I said the only things I tried are lots of repositories for explanations, next auth documentation, but I cannot seem to get it working. I have a feeling that I'm passing a lot but I can find nothing about this. I'm trying to expect a simple submit on the form then if you have access into the active directory the session gets to true (next auth) and you can access the /inventory route which is already been declared with is check of the useSession method